# GeoListPlot color function

Tags: geographics

Given a list of `{latitude, longitude, speed}` e.g.

```
data = {{28.3861, -81.4824, 11.}, {28.3861, -81.4825, 6.}, {28.386, -81.4826, 16.},
{28.3859, -81.4829, 32.}, {28.3858, -81.4832, 43.}, {28.3857, -81.4837, 51.},
{28.3856, -81.4841, 54.}, {28.3855, -81.4846, 54.},{28.3853, -81.4849, 45.},
{28.3852, -81.485, 17.},{28.3852, -81.4849, 16.}, {28.3853, -81.4847, 28.},
{28.3854, -81.4843, 45.}, {28.3855, -81.4838, 56.},{28.3857, -81.4833, 64.},
{28.3858, -81.4827, 72.},{28.386, -81.4821, 78.}, {28.3862, -81.4814, 82.},
{28.3864, -81.4807, 83.}, {28.3866, -81.48, 83.},{28.3868, -81.4793, 85.}}
```

The lat/long points can be plotting using

```
GeoListPlot[GeoPosition[Most[#]] & /@ data, 
 GeoBackground -> "StreetMap", GeoProjection -> "Mercator"]
```

[image]

How can the points be plotted using a color that is proportional to speed? Like

```
range = MinMax[data[[All, 3]]]
ColorData["ThermometerColors"][Rescale[Last[#], range]] & /@ data
```

`GeoListPlot` does not accept a `ColorFunction` option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap coordinates with `Style` using the `Rescale`d values of the third column to color the points:

```
GeoListPlot[Style @@@ 
  Transpose[{GeoPosition /@ data[[All, ;; 2]], 
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"]/@ Rescale[data[[All, -1]]]}], 
  GeoBackground -> "StreetMap", GeoProjection -> "Mercator"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this solution. If I add the `Joined -> True` option the points are joined, but the color mapping is ignored. Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: @Rohit, try `GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition /@ data[[All, ;; 2]],Style @@@ 
  Transpose[{GeoPosition /@ data[[All, ;; 2]], 
    ColorData["ThermometerColors"]/@ Rescale[data[[All, -1]]]}]}, 
  GeoBackground -> "StreetMap", GeoProjection -> "Mercator", Joined->{True, False}]`.

Comment: I see, first plot the points joined and then plot the colored points. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You may use [`GeoRegionValuePlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoRegionValuePlot.html).

```
GeoRegionValuePlot[GeoPosition@*Most@# -> Last@# & /@ data,
 GeoBackground -> "StreetMap",
 GeoProjection -> "Mercator"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
GeoListPlot[{GeoPosition[Most[#]]} & /@ data, 
  GeoBackground -> "StreetMap", GeoProjection -> "Mercator", 
  PlotLegends -> False, PlotMarkers -> Point, 
  PlotStyle -> 
  ColorConvert[(ColorData["Rainbow"][#3/85]) & @@@ data, "RGB"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Kevin. This works fine for small datasets. For large datasets ~3,000 points it is quite slow.