# Style does not work in GeoListPlot

Tags: bugs, geographics

**a bug in v12.3 and v12.3.1**

---

I'm trying to apply some styling to `GeoPosition`s

```
GeoListPlot[{{Style[
    GeoPosition[{RandomReal[{0, 90}], RandomReal[{-180, 180}]}], 
    ColorData[98, 3]]}, {Style[
    GeoPosition[{RandomReal[{0, 90}], RandomReal[{-180, 180}]}], 
    Red]}}]
```

and it seems no effect

[image]

**So how to apply custom styling to the two points?**

I'm using v12.3.1.

Comment: To me, this looks like a bug in the 12.3 (or lower). For example, none of the two solutions from [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198146/geolistplot-color-function) work in version 12.3.0.

Comment: thanks @Domen for the testing. I was suspecting so as well.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug, mentioned in another [Wolfram community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1834714) as well.

The simplest workaround, I think, is to use two separate `GeoListPlot`:

```
p1 = GeoPosition[{RandomReal[{0, 90}], RandomReal[{-180, 180}]}];
p2 = GeoPosition[{RandomReal[{0, 90}], RandomReal[{-180, 180}]}];

Show[
 GeoListPlot[{p1}, PlotStyle -> {ColorData[98, 3]}], 
 GeoListPlot[{p2}, PlotStyle -> {Red}]
]
```

[image: GeoListPlot]

Comment: Thanks for the workaround! Seems the only workaround for now. slightly disappointed by this bug.

Comment: I have tried several ways of providing different styles, but in every case it looked like `GeoListPlot` didn't traverse the style array, but instead used only the last style from the list.